# Access denied for user 'my_user'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Tags: php, mysqli, connection

Can someone explain what this means and what I can do to fix it?

The error:

> Access denied for user 'my_user'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

My php file:

```
<?php
    $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "my_db");

    $password = $_POST["password"];
    $username = $_POST["username"];

    $statement = mysqli_prepare(mysqli, "SELECT * FROM User WHERE username = ? AND password = ?");
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "ss", $username, $password);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);

    mysqli_stmt_store_result($statement);
    mysqli_stmt_bind_result($statement, $userID, $name, $age, $username, $password);

    $user = array();

    while(mysqli_stmt_fetch($statement)){
    $user[name] = $name;
    $user[age] = $age;
    $user[username] = $username;
    $user[password] = $password;
    }

    echo json_encode($user);
    mysqli_stmt_close($statement);


    mysqli_close(mysqli);

?>
```

Comment: From the info you've given, we can't really help much other than to say something along the lines of use the correct user and password that you set up in mysql.

Comment: can you still login as root?

Comment: Can I check it any other way than just to look in the data base. My system consists of a mobile application that puts up a user name, password, etc. in MySQL via a register php file. To then retrieve the information via this file ...

Comment: What do you mean by logging in as root? Is there anything you can do over a PHP file? I am very new to this !!!

Comment: error message applies to line 2!!!

Comment: your DB is on the localmachine or cpanel? if local, maybe this can help you setup your user access https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FQG-36gzWQw

Comment: It is not on the local machine, it is on a webserver ! Thanx

Answer (score 0):

Either your database user or password is wrong(or both). check again if the user does exists for that database on that host.

Also check the case of characters.

Comment: How can I check for that? Im using a mobileapplication to put in the user, password etc.. And that dosent work in the first place. But of cource I can pot them manually in the db.. But is there any easier way?

Comment: The problem is that your code cannot connect to the database. where you put the mysqli('localhost','my_user','my_password','database'); You must be sure that the username and the password used here are real and correct.

Comment: I think I dont understand what u men, sorry! But when I open the app, I print in a username and password to register a new user. What name and password are you refering to?  Do I have to put in the username and password to the db in this code? So it can connect to it? Im sorry but im relly new to this and are stressed about this and have not much time to learn, so I appreciates all help I can get! Thanx!

Comment: We are not talking about the user of your application. the user in the $_POST. I am talking about the username of the database. i think you have jumped something while learning php. PHP and the database are two differents entities, for php to use mysql it must authenticate on it, that why you put the username and the password on the mysqli function. So what i'm saying is that the username(my_user) and/or the password(my_password) are wrong. And this has nothing to do with the user of your software.

Comment: What do you use to connect to the database manually? phpmyadmin or mysql cli or benchmark?

Comment: Ok, before phpmyadmin can show the content of your database it must authenticate to the database server that what your application need to do, to connect to the database server then you will be able to use the database for storing, modifying, adding and removing data. the user of your application is just a data for the database. Now you need to connect to the database using the database server user, for example root with no password or something else. If this can't help you, i'll give up and send you to a course of php and mysql. it will help you more than this.

Comment: Yeah, thanx Fabrice Kabongo, for the explanation. Ithink I'l get it now. What you mean is that I have to look up the username and password of the phpmyadmin and print that in, in the code where it stands $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "my_db"); so that the php-file can connect to the database...

Comment: Haha yeah, you are probebly right there! I have looked up some books, but dident find any good useful explinations. But I have not so much time either. I dont think this is werry hard when you get it, but right now the time is not on my side. Thanx a lot for your time and good explinations !

Comment: Ok, will not! Thanks!